# Do animals lie?

Tags: behaviour, sociality, communication, vocal-communication

Have there been any studies that show or suggest that species known to be able to communicate information between individuals ever intentionally communicate false information i.e. lie?

(Apart from Homo of course).

Comment: Koko the gorilla once tore a sink from her living quarters, and when asked about it, blamed it on her pet kitten, signing, "Cat did it." If that's not a lie, then nothing is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been well studied by cognitive scientists who are interested in which aspects of complex human behavior are also exhibited by animals.

The only real problem here is that the word "lie" has a very complex bundle of meaning when we use it to speak about humans, and one can debate just how far various aspects of "lie" apply regarding other species. Cognitive scientists avoid this issue with more neutral terminology of ["tactical deception."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deception_in_animals#Tactical_deception)

At this point, it has been very clearly established that many species will engage in tactical deception. The most obvious and human-like manifestations (unsurprisingly) typically occur in more intelligent species with complex social interactions, such as primates and corvids.  Likewise, the subjects of deception also often occur in similar places as with humans, such as food, mating, and status/conflict.